# Google Apps Marketplace Migration

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have a Google Apps Marketplace App. Or more precisely, we have 2: one in the old marketplace and one in the new. Both point to the same URL, both do exactly the same thing (OAuth2 authenticating the user(even users from the old Marketplace,, because we handle this users like the "normal" users coming from the Chrome Web Store ).

Now Google wants us to move the users from the old Marketplace app to the new one.

How do we do that?

According to Google's document we should call an UpgradeApp API for every domain.

This requires that we find out all the domains (we don't know them because we don't care, if the user is a marketplace user or not).

So we should probably use licenseNotification on the old Marketplace app, to find out all domains and migrate them one by one?

To try this, I tried to issue the API from API Explorer (https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list)  but got a message (403 FORBIDDEN complaining that I should activate the API . How do I do this? (I already have a project where the Marketplace API and Marketplace SDK is enabled).

Will this approach work at all?

Are there simpler ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The API explorer approach works, I just tried.

Make sure you are providing correct **applicationId** which is the key here.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/`applicationId`

Comment: So, as the first step I tried to use the applicationId for new Marketplace App  (I used the Item ID in the Chrome Web Store Additional Information). This one did not work.

Comment: I also tried the listing id from the old Marketplace. This did not work either. Where will I get the correct key?